# Pandas rolling mean by year

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

Index: DatetimeIndex
Columns: Client, Business, Balances

My data goes across multiple years.  I am trying to get the rolling mean of Balances by year.  Meaning I want a variable length window which on Jan 1st of the year will be a window of size 1 and on Dec 31st will be window of size 365. Then the following year it starts over at 1 and builds from there.  I am also grouping by the Client and Business.

I have tried the following:

`df.groupby(["Client", "Business"]).rolling("AS")["Balances"].mean()`

I also tried rolling with `"A"`.

I am getting the error:

`ValueError: <YearBegin: month=1> is a non-fixed frequency`

From the documentation I thought rolling would accept and offset for variable length window but they year ones im trying arent working.

Whats the right way to do this?

Comment: `df.groupby(["Client", "Business", 'df.index.year']).expanding()["Balances"].mean()`? or `df.groupby(["Client", "Business", 'df.index.year'])["Balances"].cumsum().div(df.groupby(["Client", "Business", 'df.index.year']).cumcount().add(1))`

Comment: @ansev how will that know to start at 1 again when theres a new year?

Comment: @ansev probably groupby on `['Client','Business', df.index.year]`

Comment: You are right @QuangHoang

Comment: thank you both, looks good!

Comment: @QuangHoang update on this. dont think its working - the mean isnt correct.  for example, when i look at the first date available in a year, i would expect the value to be the exact value for that date (i.e. window size for first date is 1). but its not that. im not exactly sure where its coming from. i was playing with the axis (i.e. switching it to 1) but then it seems to just take the value for each date. any ideas?

Comment: i think it was related to getting the year from the index. when i made the year a column and grouped on that instead i got the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely because the number of days in a year is not fixed. Alternative could be to use `365d` instead as in code below using `.expanding()` [window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) and `pd.Grouper()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html). Assuming the expected output looks as below as it is not posted in the question.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
dt = [
    '2020-05-29',
    '2020-05-29',
    '2020-01-29',
    '2020-01-29',
    '2020-02-29',
    '2020-03-29',
    '2020-06-29',
    '2020-06-29'
]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dt':times
})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
df['Balances'] = np.random.randint(0,100,8)
df['Client'] = ['A','B','C','A']*2
df['Business'] = ['x','y','z','x']*2


# Groupby
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='365d'), "Client", "Business"])['Balances'].expanding().mean()
```

Output

```
dfg

dt          Client  Business   
2020-06-29  A       x         0    44.0
                              3    51.0
                              4    63.0
                              7    36.0
            B       y         1    54.0
                              5    13.0
            C       z         2    43.0
                              6    48.0
```